# SPO PowerShell to get App Display name and App Identifier from "Site App Permissions" Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, pnp-powershell, app

In SPO, how to get the App Display Name and App Identifier details which are displayed in `_layouts/15/appprincipals.aspx?Scope=Web` page using PowerShell?

`Get-PnPApp` command displays the app details installed from app store but doesn't display the app details from `_layouts/15/appprincipals.aspx?Scope=Web` page

I am not able to find any PowerShell command to get the ClientID/App Identifier details from `_layouts/15/appprincipals.aspx?Scope=Web` page.

**Update 26-Jun-2023:**

Based on Vlaad Karassev recommendation, tried using Get-PnpAzureACSPrincipal command but getting the below error:

**What am i doing wrong?**

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url "SiteURL" -TenantAdminUrl "TenantAdminSiteURL" -UseWebLogin
Get-PnPAzureACSPrincipal -scope Site -IncludeSubsites
```

[image]

Comment: try Get-PnPAzureACSPrincipal

Answer (score 1):

[Get-PnPAzureACSPrincipal](https://pnp.github.io/powershell/cmdlets/Get-PnPAzureACSPrincipal.html) Returns the list of Azure ACS Principals

Here is [my research](https://vladilen.com/office-365/track-service-principals-in-microsoft-365/) on the subject.

Comment: Yes, but there are no ways to associate the Azure ACS principals to the site where they are used . We have more than 30,000 Azure ACS principals and more than 100K sites and we find it difficult to manage the principal's information

Comment: I iterate through sites, connect to each site and run Get-PnPAzureACSPrincipal in the site context.
Also - that's what I actually do - I pull from audit logs monthly all visiting appregnew.aspx and appinv.aspx events - so I know who at least tried to use ACS principals at which site - and I know whom to contact - app owner and site owner. 
It takes up to one year to know all ACS apps owners - as secret expires after 1 year so they have to return to appinv.aspx.

Comment: @Vlaad Karassev any problem with the script i ran ?(Script updated in question) For some reason, i am getting the error for any site i use in the script:

Comment: @VlaadKarassev. Issue resolved once i used -Interactive instead of -UseWeblogin. Many thanks for your response